# Return multiple values over time

Tags: python

Okay, so is there a way to return a value from a function - the way `return` does - but not *stop* the function - the way `return` does?

I need this so I can keep returning values every so often. (Delays provided by `time.sleep()` or whatever.)

Comment: [`yield`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) may be what you're looking for

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained

Comment: If you want to return values on a timer, `yield` might not help you. You may need a thread-based or event-driven solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for `yield`.  Example:

```
import time

def myFunction(limit):
    for i in range(0,limit):
        time.sleep(2)
        yield i*i

for x in myFunction(100):
    print( x )
```

Comment: Example? Are you asking me for one? EDIT: Oh, I see, you were still editing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f():
  for i in range(10):
     yield i

g = f().next

# this is if you actually want to get a function
# and then call it repeatedly to get different values
print g()
print g()

print

# this is how you might normally use a generator
for i in f():
  print i
```

Output:

```
0
1

0
1
...
9
```

Comment: I really don't understand what your answer contributes.  And I'm not sure your even **read** the question.  Can you please comment on this?

Comment: I felt like the OP's question focused on having a function that did what he wanted, so I provided an example which gave you a function you could use more than once, in order to get those different return values. It's an addition to the classic generator example that you provided.