# Return multiple values over time in ES6 & React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, timeout, es6-promise

Okay, so is there a way to return a value from a function - the way return does - but not stop the function - the way return does?

I need this so I can keep returning values every so often.

My code looks like:

```
loopingTitleTextHandler = () => {
    const title = ["good", "cool", "887H", "Vertical"];
    for (i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
        var j = i%4;
        // loopingTitleTextHandler() // calls itself before return terminates execution 
        return title[j]; //return 0,1,2,3 in a loop with 3 second delay
    }
}
```

**My React Component**

```
<ShowTitle size={230}
    title={this.loopingTitleTextHandler()}
    color="#FDA7DC" />
```

**Edit**: I'm after a solution that solves this problem in the function like this python answer:
[Return multiple values over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567773/return-multiple-values-over-time)
but using ES6.

```py
import time

def myFunction(limit):
    for i in range(0,limit):
        time.sleep(2)
        yield i*i

for x in myFunction(100):
    print( x )
```

Comment: why dont you make use of setInterval() here, so that it executes in a fixed interval

Comment: vDog, try my solution below and let me know if that works :)

Comment: Any updates on integrating a solution? I'm really curious about what it is you are trying to create.

Comment: I haven’t had a chance to work on it since posting this yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of React, I think it would make more sense to manage these values through state. Assuming you want to return **one** new title every 3 seconds, you can do the following:

Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-rgb-n4j6z

### App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ShowTitle from "./ShowTitle";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: ["good", "cool", "887H", "Vertical"],
    currentTitle: "good"
  };

  loopingTitleTextHandler = () => {
    const { currentTitle, title } = this.state;
    const nextTitleIndex =
      title.indexOf(currentTitle) + 1 === title.length
        ? 0
        : title.indexOf(currentTitle) + 1;

    this.setState({ currentTitle: title[nextTitleIndex] });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ShowTitle
          changeTitle={this.loopingTitleTextHandler}
          currentTitle={this.state.currentTitle}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### ShowTitle.js

```
import React from "react";

class ShowTitle extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.props.changeTitle();
      console.log(this.props.currentTitle + " " + new Date().getTime());
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Title: {this.props.currentTitle}</div>;
  }
}

export default ShowTitle;
```

In the parent component (App.js) we keep track of the `currentTitle`. When `loopingTitleTextHandler()` is called, we update our state.currentTitle with the next title in the array. `currentTitle` gets passed down to `ShowTitle` component.

In Child component, we use a `setInterval()` to call `loopingTitleTextHandler()` every 3 seconds, and display the next title.

Comment: This worked, I added a few more details as I am after something that would be applicable in more scenarios. :)

Comment: @vDog ah I see, I'm not sure of a more reproducible solution, but you definitely could transform this into a hook. and use it in your other components as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `setInterval` in life-cycle hook. this will repeatedly call the function at an interval

```
  loopingTitleTextHandler = () => {
        const title = ["good", "cool", "887H", "Vertical"];
        for (i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
            var j = i%4;
            // loopingTitleTextHandler() // calls itself before return terminates execution 
            return title[j]; //return 0,1,2,3 in a loop with 3 second delay
        }
    }
```

Add `setInerval` in `componentWillMount(){}`

```
componentWillMount(){
  setInterval(()=>{
      this.loopingTitleTextHandler()
 }, 3000) // 3000 milli seconds, that is 3 sec
 }
```