# Returning generators not working on WSGI server but is fine locally

Tags: python, flask, generator, wsgi

This might be a tricky issue, but essentially, I want the server to return (yield) a text, wait for a moment, and then return another text on the same connection. Here's a sample server code:

```
from flask import Flask,request
from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__)

def generator():
    for _ in range(5):
        yield "test" #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567773/return-multiple-values-over-time
        sleep(0.5)

@app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():

    return generator() #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736527/how-can-i-yield-a-template-over-another-in-flask
```

I've tested a similar version of this code on localhost, and it worked fine. I used curl to connect to localhost, and it printed test, waited, and printed test, etc.

However, when trying to host this on pythonanywhere, it raised:

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a generator.
```

I know I can wrap it in a Response(), but that erases the time delay element. I'm not sure what to do with this.

Comment: We have some documentation on that here: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Buffering/

Comment: Wow, thanks @Glenn. Adding response.headers['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no' solved the issue.